# zephyr how to update test description

Tags: jenkins, testng, jira-zephyr

I have test running in Jenkins and I have integrated the test to display in JIRA using Zephyr

The test looks something like this -
@Test(enabled=true, description="check for OS Anomaly ")
    public void testOS4() {
....
}

and in the JIRA why dont I see any test description - the test description shows as "Creating the Test via Jenkins" (pls see the attachment). Does anybody know whats wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just verify the JSON you are PUTTING to Zephyr URL. If there is a "Description" Key with value "Created the Test via Jenkins", then you can update the key value in the JSON object. something like

```
obj.put("status", status );
obj.put("summary", summary);
obj.put("description",description);
```

Comment: let me try this and get back.

Comment: do you know where this Zephyr URL is defined ? if its defined in Jenkins we cant add Json format

Comment: does any one know how to add this ?